# Optional MongoDB .find() query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, non-relational-database

I'm building a form that filters database entry based on inputted text. It works for searching the name of the database entry but how can I make it so that it also searches the description of an entry but if nothing matches it is then ignored?

For example Database.find({name: searchText, desc: searchText}).fetch();
//searchText is a regex object

I would like to return all the things that contain searchText in name and desc but I would still like to return the ones that just match name if desc doesn't match.

Trying to do this without creating a new query as that's not necessary, is there like an optional parameter that I am missing or is this not possible?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it with a for loop.

```
let a = Database.find({name: searchText}).fetch();
let b = Database.find({desc: searchText}).fetch();
for(let c in b){
   a.push(b[c])
}
return b;
```

Just incase anyone has a similar issue.
Please still answer if there is a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [OR](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or) operator? For me it seems that should be enough for your case.